# Problem HTTP error 403 in Python Web Scraping

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I was trying to scrape a website, but I kept on getting the HTTP Error 403. How to avoid 403 issue for the URL below?

Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://hayabusa.open2ch.net/test/read.cgi/livejupiter/1700322786/l50'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print('res=', res)
```

The error I get is:

```
res
<Response [403]>
```

I also tried more headers as following `but it didn't work:

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.google.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'cookie': 'SID=ZAjX93QUU1NMI2Ztt_dmL9YRSRW84IvHQwRrSe1lYhIZncwY4QYs0J60X1WvNumDBjmqCA.; __Secure- 
    #..,
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"x86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"115.0.5790.110"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Not/A)Brand";v="99.0.0.0", "Google Chrome";v="115.0.5790.110", "Chromium";v="115.0.5790.110"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'Windows',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '15.0.0',
    'sec-ch-ua-wow64': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-client-data': '#..',
}
```

Comment: 403 basically means the server decided it didn't want to talk to you.  Maybe because it thinks you're a robot, or it doesn't like your network domain, or any of a hundred other reasons.

Answer (score -2):

In your case, you've already added a 'User-Agent' header to mimic a browser, which is a good start. However, it seems like the website is still detecting that your request is not coming from a regular browser. Here are a few things you can try:

### Add More Headers:

Try to mimic the headers sent by a real browser more closely. You've already added a 'User-Agent', but you might need to include more headers. For example, include headers like 'Accept', 'Accept-Language', 'Accept-Encoding', and 'Connection'.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
}
```

## Set a Valid Referer:

Set a 'Referer' header to a URL that makes sense for the website you are trying to scrape. In your case, you've set it to Google, but you might need to set it to a URL related to the website you're scraping.

### Session Persistence:

Use a persistent session to maintain the state of your connection across multiple requests. This can be done using the Session object in the requests library.

```
import requests

url = 'https://hayabusa.open2ch.net/test/read.cgi/livejupiter/1700322786/l50'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.google.com/'
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    res = session.get(url)

print('res=', res)
```

### Check for Additional Protection:

Some websites use more advanced methods like CAPTCHA or JavaScript challenges to protect against scraping. If that's the case, you might need to use tools like Selenium to automate a real browser.